# numpy allclose vs mpmath almosteq

Tags: python, numpy, precision, mpmath

```py
abs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * abs(b))
```

vs

```py
(abs(a - b) <= atol
 or
 abs(a - b) / max(abs(a), abs(b)) < rtol)
```

Docs: [numpy.allclose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html), [mpmath.almosteq](https://mpmath.org/doc/current/general.html?mpmath.almosteq#mpmath.almosteq) -- Source: [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.25.0/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2170-L2242), [mpmath](https://github.com/mpmath/mpmath/blob/1.3.0/mpmath/ctx_base.py)

How do these schemes differ? An obvious one is that `allclose` is `and` while `almosteq` is `or` with respect to the tolerances. To me the `and` makes more sense, yet `mpmath` is a library dedicated to precision, so I find this strange.

When is `almosteq` preferred over `allclose`, speed/memory aside? (Optional question, can one's `rtol` be converted to another's rough equivalent)?

Comment: One key difference is that the former is _not_ symmetric while the latter is. `allclose(a, b)` is _not_ the same as `allclose(b, a)`, whereas `almosteq(a, b)` is the same as `almosteq(b, a)`.